# Android Browser Web page one time login

Tags: android, browser, web

I have username and password of user stored in my database, like one time login. Now each time user opens the web page i need not show the login screen, rather i should directly show the user his home page/ mail page. I am able to store the user credentials in my DB, however I am searching for a way to send these details to the server that, each time user opens the web page (like gmail.com) It will send the user home page/Mail inbox to me rather than sending User login screen. Will this credentials(user name, password, url) be sent in the form of url to the server? where is this logic defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learned that Login Screen for any browser page will be shown always, if you have the user credentials stored in your db it will do a auto fill of the form and user still have to select login. This case is different for the apps(Like facebook, twitter) stored on phone as they use AccountManager to get the authentication. However this is not the case with Browser.